# Range.Copy to another worksheet in an open workbook won't run, Script out of range error

Tags: vba, excel, copy, copy-paste

I have a code to copy and paste from sheet1 in workbook1 to sheet1 in workbook2, but it won't run because of Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

The code is as follows;

```
Sub Range_Copy_Example()
     Workbooks("Book1.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy _
           Workbooks("Book2.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

I have book1 as my active workbook, I have book2 open.  I am not entirely sure why this won't run, as I am following along with this video and believe my code matches his... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfspd_QdbMg&index=6&list=PLKbOx3gUV_E87DSMLQFKdYy2XxwrcBA19&t=221s

Please explain what the heck is going on!!!  Many thanks!

Comment: Are the workbooks actually saved as '97-2003 .xls workbooks or are they unsaved workbooks or are they 2007-2016 xlsx workbooks or something else altogether (xlm, xla, xlsm, xlsb, etc)? Have you tried dropping the .xls off each workbook name?

Comment: That means, your workbooks are not saved. Save them and the code will recognize them as you want.

Comment: Possibly your two files are open in different instances of Excel.

Comment: What Jeeped said, Also are your sheets actually called "Sheet1" ?

Comment: @sktneer, Thank you. I tried saving them this morning and running the code, works perfectly.

Comment: @TimothyVrancic You're welcome! Glad your issue is resolved. :)